# Foundation Vertical X-Y Grid: content 100vh and responsive in grid-y

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation, responsive-images

Using FoundationPress to build a WordPress theme. On the homepage, I would like to create a vertical grid layout using Foundation's `grid-y medium-grid-frame` [vertical grid](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html#vertical-grids) to keep all content within the viewport. Therefore the content in the `<main>` element to **not** expand beyond the `footer`. The images will always respond to the height of the viewport. Right now it is wrong:

[Screenshot of overflow issue](https://ibb.co/MkJby9s)

So the footer should always be at the bottom of the viewport and no vertical scrolling, with the `<main>` content fitting nicely inside and responding to any screen size. Unless its mobile, then the footer will be at the bottom of the stacked images. Seems super basic.

Here is the site in question https://comedydynamics.com, I tried to replicate on a CodePen, but it doesnt turn out the same.

Tried to instead use the `x-grid`, but no luck. Was messing around with CSS position, overflow, even different display options. Really stumped on this one.

My theme code:

```
<?php $post_objects = get_field('home_feat_posts');

    if ($post_objects): ?>

    <?php foreach ($post_objects as $post_object): ?>

        <a class="cell medium-6 large-offset-1 large-5 img-container" href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_object->ID); ?>">

            <?php

            $image = get_field('home_image', $post_object->ID);

            $size = 'fp-xlarge'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)

            if ($image) {
                echo wp_get_attachment_image($image, $size);
            }

            ?>

        </a>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

The output:

```
<main class="grid-y">

    <div class="cell medium-auto medium-cell-block-container home-container">

        <div class="grid-x pt-2 pb-2">

            <a href="" class="cell medium-6 large-offset-1 large-5 img-container">

                <img width="750" height="404" src="//localhost:3000/. . ." class="attachment-fp-xlarge size-fp-xlarge" alt=". . ." srcset="//localhost:3000/. . . 750w, //localhost:3000/. . . 300w, //localhost:3000/. . . 640w" sizes="(max-width: 639px) 98vw, (max-width: 1199px) 64vw, 750px">

            </a>

            <a href="" class="cell medium-6 large-offset-1 large-5 img-container">

                <img width="750" height="404" src="//localhost:3000/. . ." class="attachment-fp-xlarge size-fp-xlarge" alt=". . ." srcset="//localhost:3000/. . . 750w, //localhost:3000/. . . 300w, //localhost:3000/. . . 640w" sizes="(max-width: 639px) 98vw, (max-width: 1199px) 64vw, 750px">

            </a>

            <a href="" class="cell medium-6 large-offset-1 large-5 img-container">

                <img width="750" height="404" src="//localhost:3000/. . ." class="attachment-fp-xlarge size-fp-xlarge" alt=". . ." srcset="//localhost:3000/. . . 750w, //localhost:3000/. . . 300w, //localhost:3000/. . . 640w" sizes="(max-width: 639px) 98vw, (max-width: 1199px) 64vw, 750px">

            </a>

            <a href="" class="cell medium-6 large-offset-1 large-5 img-container">

                <img width="750" height="404" src="//localhost:3000/. . ." class="attachment-fp-xlarge size-fp-xlarge" alt=". . ." srcset="//localhost:3000/. . . 750w, //localhost:3000/. . . 300w, //localhost:3000/. . . 640w" sizes="(max-width: 639px) 98vw, (max-width: 1199px) 64vw, 750px">

            </a>

        </div>

    </div>

</main>
```

Could this have to do with my image sizing in WordPress?

Hope I gave enough info, haha.

Thanks!

[See the Pen](https://codepen.io/luukee/pen/WPpGOj/)

Our objective:

[What we want. No overflow of main content](https://ibb.co/MkJby9s)